How to ensure proper call order when using decorators on overridden methods in TypeScript?
I have a problem with using decorator to an overridden method. Here is a simplified example presenting my problem:
function decorator(nameOrNameFn: string | ((...args: any[]) => string)) {
    return function (value: Function, context: ClassMethodDecoratorContext) {
        return function (this: any, ...args: any[]) {
            console.log('Calling from decorator start');
            const name = typeof nameOrNameFn === 'function' ? nameOrNameFn(...[...args, this]) : nameOrNameFn;
            value.apply(this, args);
            console.log('Calling from decorator end');
        };
    };
}

class BaseClass {
    protected constructor() {
        this.extendWaitToBeDisplayed();
    }

    private extendWaitToBeDisplayed(): void {
        const original = this.waitToBeDisplayed;
        this.waitToBeDisplayed = () => {
            original.apply(this);
            console.log('Calling from extendWaitToBeDisplayed() end')
        };
    }

    public waitToBeDisplayed(): void {
        console.log('calling waitToBeDisplayed() from BaseClass')
    }
}


class SubClass extends BaseClass {
    public constructor() {
        super();
    }

    @decorator('"User management" page is displayed')
    public override waitToBeDisplayed(): void {
        console.log('calling waitToBeDisplayed() from SubClass')
    }
}

new SubClass().waitToBeDisplayed();

This example in TypeScript Playground
This solution with using extendWaitToBeDisplayed() in constructor of BaseClass is added here on purpose. I wanted to make sure that it is called always, even when waitToBeDisplayed() is overridden and called without super.waitToBeDisplayed().
When I run this code, it prints:
[LOG]: "Calling from decorator start" 
[LOG]: "calling waitToBeDisplayed() from SubClass" 
[LOG]: "Calling from decorator end" 
[LOG]: "Calling from extendWaitToBeDisplayed() end" 

I would like it to run in this order:
[LOG]: "Calling from decorator start" 
[LOG]: "calling waitToBeDisplayed() from SubClass" 
[LOG]: "Calling from extendWaitToBeDisplayed() end" 
[LOG]: "Calling from decorator end" 

So console.log('Calling from extendWaitToBeDisplayed() end') would be called “inside” the decorator.
Is it possible to do this? This BaseClass is extended by hundreds of other classes, and I would like to make changes preferably in it (or eventually @decorator). Not all SubClasses already use this decorator, and not all of them override this waitToBeDisplayed() method. I would like to make it work also in these classes.

This is a mess because you're taking a decorated method and turning it into a field, but you want the method to be undecorated, then apparently turned into a field, and then that field should be decorated.  But that's not how decorators work, especially if you're using a method decorator.  Yuck, I don't know how to get this to do what you want.
